# error on BQ No matching signature for operator AND for argument types: BOOL, STRING. Supported signature: BOOL AND

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, boolean-expression, typecasting-operator

I am trying to retrieve data from two specific locations on BQ and getting this error: No matching signature for operator AND for argument types: BOOL, STRING. Supported signature: BOOL AND

I am guessing the query is matching two separate data type and I have to peform a CAST function. But how do I write the query to receive the desired output? This Big Query is highlighting on "Bangladesh" so I am thinking I might need to change the datatype on that.

Below is my code:

```
SELECT location, date, total_cases, total_deaths,population, (total_cases/population)*100 as death_percentage
FROM `my-project-72222022.PortfolioProject.CovidDeaths` 
WHERE location = "Bangladesh" AND "United States"
ORDER BY 1, 2
LIMIT 1000
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match multiple values you need to use IN or have multiple clauses in your WHERE statement e.g.

```
WHERE location IN ("Bangladesh", "United States")

WHERE location = "Bangladesh" 
OR location = "United States"
```